# shell_exec not executing sh file for inkscape command

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell-exec, inkscape

one.sh

```
#! bin/bash
command="cp 357.svg 000.svg"
echo "Executing Command";
exec $command;
```

from shell by executing `sh one.sh` runs perfact and even in php `shell_exec("sh one.sh");` works fine.

two.sh

```
#! bin/bash
command="/usr/bin/inkscape -f 357.svg -e 357.png"
echo "Executing Command";
exec $command;
```

From shell `sh two.sh` works fine

**but using php** `shell_exec("sh two.sh")` **not executing**

can any one please tell why it is not executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
echo shell_exec("sh two.sh 2>&1;")
```

and see what the output is, maybe it will give you a permission denied error.
Maybe also worth checking which user you are running with (probably something like www-data)

Comment: WARNING:Unable to create profile directory(Permission denied) Message:Cannot create profile directory /var/www/.config/inkscape. Message: Inkscape will run with default settings, and new settings will not be saved. (inkscape:..):libgnomevfs-WARNING:Unable to create ~/.gnome2 directory:Permission denied Emergency save activated! Emergency save completed. Inkscape will close now. If you can reproduce this crash, Message: Error: Inkscape encountered an internal error and will close now. Segmentation fault

Comment: I don't know if you are able to change things on the server but the message is clear: inkscape wants to create a config dir and it is not allowed to.

To test is really quick and dirty:
    (sudo) chmod 0777 /var/www/.config/inkscape 


Or:
set the correct directory permissions so your user (assuming www-data) may write in that directory

Comment: @klapvee Thanks for that. I had the same Inkscape error message when running it from a PHP script. I then logged in as www-data and executed exactly the same command, which produced the same warnings, but it *worked!* I concluded that the missing .gnome2 directory could not be a problem. For whatever reason, adding it actually did fix the inkscape crash. (For information: /var/www/.gnome2 by default. To make sure you have the right path, check the output of `strace inkscape --with-your-args`.)